# Select top chapters from Bible Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a KJV database of the bible laid out as follows:

```
`book`,`chapter`,`verse`,`contents`
'Genesis','1','1','In the beginning'
```

But what I want to be able to do is return the book, and the amount of chapters that it involves.  Somehow I need to get distinct rows, but I am not sure how to find out the max available amount of chapters.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `book`, MAX(`chapter`) FROM `bible-kjv`
```

But that only returns to the biggest chapters (150) which I think is from Psalms.

how can I acheive this?

Comment: You will need to `GROUP BY` book to make this work.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT book,COUNT(chapter) FROM bible-kjv GROUP BY book`

Comment: For others, who may read this after all these years: The query shown is invalid, but MySQL is run in a mode where it doesn't report this. Hence my advice: Never use MySQL without having `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to get out of this allow-me-to-write-invalid-queries-mode (which shouldn't exist in the first place in my opinion). Fortunately, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is the default mode in recent MySQL versions at least.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `GROUP BY book` in order to get a row for each book of the bible:

```
SELECT `book`, MAX(`chapter`) 
FROM `bible-kjv`
GROUP BY `book`
```

Using an aggregate function like `MAX`, *without* a `GROUP BY` clause, just returns a single row with the maximum chapter value.

Comment: Agh! I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and examine the Bible database in public domain here for easy query.
https://github.com/fangniude/bible-data

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31967490)